# Getting error while executing Cmd command from Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt, selenium-grid

Please find below stacktrace for the exception

> ```
> 2016-12-28 16:22:15.685:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
> 2016-12-28 16:22:15.706:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
> 2016-12-28 16:22:15.711:WARN:osjuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444: java.net.BindException: Address already
> ```
>
> in use: JVM_Bind
>       java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)

The above stacktrace explain about the exception in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

The exception suggests that you've got another process bound to the same port.

I assume you're running it on **Windows** :

The below would list all the ports and processes which are being listened:

```
netstat -ano
```

And then you could kill the process by using the pid:

```
 taskkill -pid 011 /f <-- 011 is just a sample pid
```

Maybe you might have to have a look at this [blog post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/address-already-use-jvm-bind-exception.html) for a better understanding.

Comment: Actually i am running this command from java so java process is active, again i am making another process of java as when i am giving command i am using java executor so port for java is already listening so how can i make two process run on same port that is the issue, so every time when i am executing my test scripts i need to manually execute hub and node commands on cmd, so i am trying to avoid it by executing it once throughout the execution of test with java, so need a way to that i mean need a code to do that.